# Dynamic image loading and event binding using JSON, AJAX and JQuery

Tags: json, jquery, dynamic

I want to add images to my website dynamically. When a user clicks a button, an ajax call through jquery is made to server, a json file is returned containing image urls and ids. I want to render these images on my webpage, then change their style(display based on some condition) and then add click events to these images (a single event handler that will capture the id of the image raising the event).
Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself at all, or are you looking to get someone to do the work for you?

Comment: @ScottGress, i tried it but the style of image added dynamically was not changing, although for images added statically, i was able to change the styles using $("#item").css("style","value").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create image element as follows.

```
var img=document.createElement("img");
img.onclick=function() { /* js code here*/ };
img.src="http://example.com/example.jpg";
img.style.display="block";
/* or give css class, image.className="picture" */
```

then append in somewhere in div named "imagecontainer" for example in 
`<div id="imagecontainer">`

```
document.getElementById("imagecontainer").appendChild(img);
```

Then done :)

p.s. Don't you have ajax code? This url will help you, just append this code in the sample code, then done. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly. Can i call another function from the event-handler function, e.g.: 
img.onclick=function(){ another_func(id_of_clickd_element); };
I tried this but its not working.

Comment: Normally you can, what error you get? or you can do something like too function another_func() { /* this.id */ }; and img.onclick=another_func;

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

**HTML**

```
<img id="15623" src="img/default.jpg" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img').click(function () {
    var context = $(this);
    $.getJSON('/getImage.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id'), function (json) {
        context.attr('src', json.url);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
//db connection

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (is_numeric($id)) {
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT url FROM img WHERE id = '.$id);
    $res = mysql_result($query, 0);
    return '{"url": "'.$res.'"}';
}
```